# PHPUnit picking up on syslog messages?

Tags: php, logging, phpunit, syslog

I am testing a logger class with a method that opens a log like so:

```
openlog($this->identifier, $this->option, $this->facility);
syslog($level, $message)
closelog();
```

The `$facility` that my logger writes to is currently set as `LOCAL0`

When I unit test my logger I get the following message:

```
Broadcast message from systemd-journald@myWS:

phpserver7.0[9125]: Logger message
```

How can I suppress this message with PHPUnit or in my code?

Edit:

This only seems to happen when I log a message with a severity of "emergency" meaning a severity level of 0.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog#Severity_level

Wikipedia states:

> This level should not be used by applications.

Still, it is part of the PSR-3 logger abstract though so I would just like to be able to suppress the message with PHPUnit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test method, you can suppress output by wrapping an output buffer around your call that produces output. Example:

```
/**
 * @preserveGlobalState disabled
 * @runInSeparateProcess
 */
public function testOutputCanSend()
{
    ob_start();

    // Do some stuff here that outputs directly, e.g
    openlog($this->identifier, $this->option, $this->facility);
    syslog($level, $message)
    closelog();

    ob_end_clean();
}
```